# Group by index column compare their area and add values to a new column in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, geopandas

I have these columns:

```
index, area_of_poly, cad_admin
```

I have to group by index (it is a normal column called index) in order to take the rows that have the same value.

```
#all the ones, all the twos, etc
```

Some of them (rows) are unique though.
About the ones that are not unique now:

What I have done so far:
I have to check with a `group by` which of the groups have the largest area and give its respected `cad_admin` value to the others in its group in a new column called `cad_admin1`. 
The unique values are going to still have the same value they had in `cad_admin` in the now `cad_admin1` column.

more info:

the dataset: http://www.mediafire.com/file/x4q5k7xuztq6o3w/p.zip

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
inte=gpd.read_file('in.shp')


inte['index'].value_counts()[inte['index'].value_counts()>1]


359    9
391    8
376    7
374    6
354    5
446    4
403    4
348    4
422    4
424    4
451    4
364    3
315    3
100    3
245    3




inte["rank_gr"] = inte.groupby("index")["area_of_poly"].rank(ascending = False, method = 
"first")
inte["key1_temp"] = inte.apply(lambda row: str(row[""]) if row["rank_gr"] == 1.0
else "", axis = 1)
inte["CAD_ADMIN_FINAL"] = inte.groupby("index")["key1_temp"].transform("sum")
print (inte[["area_of_poly", "index", "CAD_ADMIN", "CAD_ADMIN_FINAL"]])
```

This code as you will see produces some errors like:

```
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
KeyError: ('', 'occurred at index 0')
```

An example of an output and input that works is this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"index": [1,2,3,5,1,2,3,3,3], "area": 
[50,60,70,80,90,100,10,20,70], "key0": ["1f",2,"3d",4,5,6,7,8,9]})
print df

# INPUT
area  index key0
  50      1   1f
  60      2    2
  70      3   3d
  80      5    4
  90      1    5
 100      2    6
  10      3    7
  20      3    8
  70      3    9

df["rank_gr"] = df.groupby("index")["area"].rank(ascending = False, method = 
"first")
df["key1_temp"] = df.apply(lambda row: str(row["key0"]) if row["rank_gr"] == 1.0 
else "", axis = 1)
df["key1"] = df.groupby("index")["key1_temp"].transform("sum")
print df[["area", "index", "key0", "key1"]]


# OUTPUT
area  index key0 key1
  50      1   1f    5
  60      2    2    6
  70      3   3d   3d
  80      5    4    4
  90      1    5    5
 100      2    6    6
  10      3    7   3d
  20      3    8   3d
  70      3    9   3d
```

Appreciate any efforts in resolving this because I am trying to solve it for 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

```
inte["key1_temp"] = inte.apply(lambda row: str(row[""]) if 
row["rank_gr"] == 1.0
else "", axis = 1)
```

In this code str(row[""]) mention the column you want to manipulate